# Is it possible to compile HTML markup to templatable javascript on Coldfusion server-side?

Tags: javascript, templates, coldfusion, compilation, server-side

I have been looking at Javascript templating engines trying to find a way to have standard templates available on/offline.

Currently I'm kind of stuck at [dustjs/linkedIn](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs) which would require to server-side pre-compile a template into a `js`file - difficult as I'm using `Coldfusion8`.

There are sparse links available on running Javascript in Coldfusion ([example](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1766-Running-Javascript-In-ColdFusion-With-CFGroovy-And-Rhino.htm)). So:

**Question:**
Is there an easy to use Javascript in Coldfusion? I'm not talking about `toScript` our `<cfoutput><script>alert("hello")></cfoutput>`, I want to run a javascript function like the dustjs compiler on the server in a cfscheduled task to take HTML templates and compile them from this:

```
  Hello {name}! You have {count} new messages.
```

to this:

```
(function() {
    dust.register("demo", body_0);

    function body_0(chk, ctx) {
    return chk.write("Hello ").reference(ctx.get("name"), ctx, "h").write("! You have ").reference(ctx.get("count"), ctx, "h").write(" new messages.");
    }
    return body_0;
})();
```

which is done in the dustJS [compiler.js](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/blob/master/lib/compiler.js) file (I think...). If it's not possible, what are other options besides creating a "coldfusion compiler" which changes markup to compiled javascript?

Thanks for some toughts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [CFGroovy](http://www.barneyb.com/barneyblog/projects/cfgroovy2/). Although targeting groovy, it's really a way for CF to use the generic scripting features of Java (JSR-223) You ought to be able to start Rhino through this and run your code. In fact, Ben Nadel has an [article on doing this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1766-Running-Javascript-In-ColdFusion-With-CFGroovy-And-Rhino.htm).

Althernatively, you could put node on your server and use cfexecute to run node to compile your templates.

If you make it work, I'd consider not compiling on a schedule. Perhaps try one fo the following:

- Compile as part of your build, if you have a defined build process.
- Compile on demand, so your script URLs might be script.cfm?script=whatever.js and have CF check dates and either compile the template or
- Use the DirectoryWatcher event gateway to monitor your script folder and compile-on-change.

I like the third option best, as it'll only compile on change, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Awesome! I found the link to Ben Nadels post, too, but didn't know about directoryWatcher. Cool! I'm trying `cfgroovy` and `dirWatcher` now. Must be able to get this to work.

Comment: I wish I could take credit, I'm BarnyR rather than BarneyB :)

Comment: although it's not you, do you have a link on how to setup CfGroovy... Can't get it to work.