# How to add a pure javascript compiler plugin server-side when running CFGroovy in Coldfusion?

Tags: javascript, compilation, coldfusion, server-side, cfimport

I'm trying to sell myself to the idea of trying to build enhanced Jquery Mobile markup on the server (running `Coldfusion8`) and then try to use [DustJS](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/) (Javascript templating engine) to precompile the markup into a js string, which I want to server as a static file.

I think I have it down to trying to add the plugin in Coldfusion. Here is what I want to do:

Start with a template like this in Coldfusion:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="renderedResults">
    <cfoutput>
        {##person}{root}: {name}, {age}{/person}
    </cfoutput> 
</cfsavecontent>
```

Running this through the [DustJS](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/) compiler on NodeJS returns something like this:

```
 (function() {
      dust.register("demo", body_0);

 function body_0(chk, ctx) {
     return chk.section(ctx.get("person"), ctx, {
       "block": body_1
      }, null);
   }
   function body_1(chk, ctx) {
     return chk.reference(ctx.get("root"), ctx, "h").write(": ").reference(ctx.get("name"), ctx, "h").write(", ").reference(ctx.get("age"), ctx, "h");
   }
   return body_0;
 })();
```

which I then save as `someStaticTemplate.js`. This file is pulled in on the client and filled with dynmic data.

My problem is compiling this in Coldfusion.

I'm using [`Cfgroovy`](http://www.barneyb.com/barneyblog/projects/cfgroovy2/) in order to run Javascript on the server:

```
 <cfimport prefix="g" taglib="../../tags/cfgroovy/" />
     35k zipped plugin here
     <!--- COMPILE  --->
     var dustedTemplate = dust.compile( variables.tempLateToCompile, variables.templateName);
     <!--- OUT --->
     variables.put("renderedResult", dustedTemplate);
 </g:script>
```

However doing it like this returns the following error:

```
type: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.JavaScriptException 
message: [object Error] (<Unknown Source>#1)
```

So I must be doing something wrong...

**Question:**

Is it possible at all to compile this server-side into JS? If so, any idea how to include the plugin. I have also looked at [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1767-Running-Javascript-And-jQuery-In-ColdFusion-With-CFGroovy-And-Rhino.htm) post, but I'm already stretching what I can do, so I'm hoping this can work out as I'm trying above.

Thanks for some inputs!

**BOUNTY**:
Ok, I give up trying myself. Bounty time... I'm looking for a Coldfusion code snippet that allows me to
a) load the DustJS plugin in a CFGrooy tag or alternative javascript enabling setting
b) let's me run the DustJS Javascript-compile function to turn my template from

```
  {##person}{root}: {name}, {age}{/person}
```

into this:

```
  (function() {
      dust.register("demo", body_0);

 function body_0(chk, ctx) {
     return chk.section(ctx.get("person"), ctx, {
       "block": body_1
      }, null);
   }
   function body_1(chk, ctx) {
     return chk.reference(ctx.get("root"), ctx, "h").write(": ").reference(ctx.get("name"), ctx, "h").write(", ").reference(ctx.get("age"), ctx, "h");
   }
   return body_0;
 })();
```

If that is not possible technically, I'm open for alternative approaches, that allow me to create a template on the server, which is HTML based and includes placeholder so I can add dynamic data on the client.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need the Rhino jar if you want to execute JS using BB's CFGroovy. Have you included it in your class path?

Comment: mh. No I haven't. I just tried to follow [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1766-Running-Javascript-In-ColdFusion-With-CFGroovy-And-Rhino.htm) example using `<cfimport prefix="g" taglib="../cfgroovy/" />`. But I followed the post and checked for installed factories. Rhino was in there, so I thought I would be ok.

Comment: Here's a similar [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742741/is-it-possible-to-compile-html-markup-to-templatable-javascript-on-coldfusion-se) that may be useful.

Comment: @krg: that question was asked by ... me. I'm following the info I got there but cannot get it to work, so I posted the bounty for someone telling me what is wrong in my code.

Comment: I've taken a pop at this and cannot make it work. I can get Rhino to load dust (apparently) but it claims that the 'compile' function isn't present. I managed to dump out what rhino thought dust was and it only showed dust.cache (the first element defined) to that may be a clue?

Comment: mh. let me check. Sounds like as far as I'm getting :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1766-Running-Javascript-In-ColdFusion-With-CFGroovy-And-Rhino.htm

and [Is it possible to compile HTML markup to templatable javascript on Coldfusion server-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742741/is-it-possible-to-compile-html-markup-to-templatable-javascript-on-coldfusion-se)

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: So the answer to your question is I should look at the my other question plust the links I provided there and try to figure this subject and try to figure it out by myself. Well... I was expecting a little more help or some info on what I'm doing wrong.